# Bad GET URL when using the Logstash http_poller input plugin

Tags: logstash

Trying to pull data from a public API using the Logstash http_poller input plugin:

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      method => "GET"
      url => "https://api.example.com/v1/service/"
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    schedule => { cron => "0 * * * *"}
    codec => "json"
    metadata_target => "http_poller_metadata"
  }
}

filter {
}

output {
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
  }
}
```

Keep on getting a bad get URL error:

```
[ERROR][logstash.pipeline] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: Invalid URL GET>...]
```

Any idea what's causing this? The URL for the API is correct...

Comment: I think that the GET in `method => "GET"` shouldn't be in quotes. At least in the examples I've found, it's not the case. Can you try `method => GET`?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the `method => "GET"` line. Removing it worked like a charm.